# SQL to LINQ in C# (query with several tables and alias)

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

Is there somebody that could translate this query to Linq in C# . I was searching and I didn't find any query similiar to.
Thanks a lot guys!
SQL Sentence:

```
SELECT a.Amenaza, c.Nombre, c.Descripcion
 FROM AmenazasEstablecer a, ControlesEstablecer c, Matriz_Amenazas_ControlesEstablecer m
 WHERE a.IdAmenaza = m.IdAmenaza AND c.IdControl=m.IdControl;
```

Comment: can you show your C# code? DataContext? object names? etc?

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing an implied join rather that having an ON clause?

Answer (score 5):

You will have to have a DataContext created and specified, but once you do you could get away with:

```
MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext("SomeConnectionString");

var results = from a in context.AmenazasEstablecer
              from c in context.ControlesEstablecer
              from m in context.Matriz_Amenazas_ControlesEstablecer
              where a.IdAmenaza == m.IdAmenaza && c.IdControl == m.IdControl
              select new {
                  a.Amenaza,
                  c.Nombre,
                  c.Descripcion
              });
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var results = from a in context.AmenazasEstablecer 
              join m in context.Matriz_Amenazas_ControlesEstablecer 
                          on  a.IdAmenaza equals m.IdAmenaza
              join c in context.ControlesEstablecer 
                          on c.IdControl equals m.IdControl
             select new {a.Amenaza, c.Nombre, c.Descripcion};
```

Comment: @Adrian: I'm in the same boat. I think they're cleaner. I actually started writing this exact code out for my answer but changed it when I realized that OP was asking specifically for a cross join. I upvoted this answer anyway.